# Check if block is visible

Tags: blocks, 8

I'm on Drupal 8,

I'm using `\Drupal::entityQuery('block')` to get the list of blocks.

Now I want to determine if the block is visible for:

- Current Page (Content Type)
- Current User (Role)
- Current Path

I want this information according to visibility settings configured in block's configuration.

I can use `$block->getVisibility()` method when I load the block and there I can iterate through visibility settings and find out if the block is visible or not.

I wander if there is a better and easier way to do this??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Checking view access to a block includes visibility checks. so you can just do this: `if ($block->access('view'))`.

Why do you want this information? block.module has a block.repository service with a `getVisibleBlocksPerRegion()` which gives you exactly that. a list of visible blocks, grouped by region.

Comment: Hi @Berdir, 

Thank you for your answer, it worked and did what I wanted :)

The reason I'm doing this is that I have some blocks I want to print in `{{ page_bottom }}` not in a region. 

I need this because I want to have functionality where users will be able to embed third party services at the bottom of the page.

Comment: I see. Not sure about your structure, but by default, page_bottom is immediately after page. So why not just make a block region that's at the end of page.html.twig and place your blocks there?

Comment: Good point, I thought about that but we had a requirement in which user doesn't have to add region manually.

If user installs module it should work without adding a new region.

Answer (score 0):

`$block->access('view')` is helping me check if a particular block is accessible on the current page or not.

I need something that can help me check block access for some other page as well. For eg., I provide `page_url` and it returns if a block is accessible on that given page or not.

Any suggestions will really help.